# How to drag and move icons in the Gnome-shell favourites bar?

Tags: gnome-shell

I'm using Gnome-shell in Ubuntu 11.10, and I love the layout but when I add an application to the favourites panel on the left side, it shoves it at the bottom and I like to arrange them around on the bar.

I tried left clicking, holding down, right clicking, after about a minute I found out, that I had to hold down the scroll wheel to move them, but it's so damn tricky, sometimes it works and sometimes it just does nothing, is it actually the scroll wheel I need to be holding down? or is there another mouse button I need too? I've only successfully managed to move an icon twice, other times I sat down holding down the scroll wheel forever just trying to move an icon, why does it have to be like this?

Please help!

Answer (score 20):

Click with the left mouse button, drag a bit to the right, find the spot you want to rearrange it to and leave the mouse button

[image]

Dont mind the blue, its caused by the screencast tool

Answer (score 2):

If you can't move the icon by dragging it with the mouse then install cursor theme:

```
sudo apt-get install oxygen-cursor-theme
```

and go to Tweak Tool,

[image]

change the cursor theme and then it should work!

Comment: How, exactly, is changing the cursor theme enabling mouse dragging?

Comment: This was a specific bug only on Ubuntu 16.04 and installing another cursor theme pulled in some additional cursor types (for dragging) and made the dragging work.
This problem also was known when someone installs an extension for launcher bar and messes up the original one
On which Ubuntu version are you?

Comment: I'm not on Ubuntu but I couldn't understand how a cursor theme would impact this problem, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to click on "activities" in the top left corner, then drag and drop the starter icons just as you like.

Comment: What's the difference with [Amith KK's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/112226/349837)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Gnome-Shell: Klick and hold the icon you want to move and, pull it out to the right and place it at the the position you like. That's it.