# How to drag and move icons in Ubuntu 18.04.1 favourites bar?

Tags: icons, favorites

How do I drag and move icons in Ubuntu 18.04.1 favourites bar?
I've tried all the suggestions at [How-to-drag-and-move-icons-in-the-gnome-shell-favourites-bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87629/how-to-drag-and-move-icons-in-the-gnome-shell-favourites-bar) (@2018-01-10) but they didn't work for me.

Comment: did you install dash to dock or using default ubuntu dock?

Comment: Huh? Whatever it installed out the box. I also installed GNONE tweaks 3.28.1 & oxygen-cursor-theme

Comment: can you paste the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`

Comment: gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop', 'gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'org.gnome.Cheese.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'grsync.desktop', 'geany.desktop', 'virtualbox.desktop', 'alacarte.desktop', 'simple-scan.desktop', 'k4dirstat.desktop']
P.S. I can drag/move favourite icons with my old PC with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Ok, just to check, run this command `gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "[ 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop', 'gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'org.gnome.Cheese.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'grsync.desktop', 'alacarte.desktop', 'simple-scan.desktop', 'k4dirstat.desktop', 'geany.desktop', 'virtualbox.desktop' ]"`

Comment: did the order of icons changed with above command?

Comment: to revert back to your original icons order `gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop', 'gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'org.gnome.Cheese.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'grsync.desktop', 'geany.desktop', 'virtualbox.desktop', 'alacarte.desktop', 'simple-scan.desktop', 'k4dirstat.desktop']"`

Comment: did you upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04? by default, in fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 there is no problem.

Comment: Aha! That re-organised the icons. And this is a fresh install on empty drive.

Comment: Ok, you can organize the order by editing your app names in gsettings command above..time being.. meanwhile i am testing  the otherway to reinstall ubuntu dock. by the way can you paste the out put of `ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

Comment: `$ ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com  ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it using the `dconf` editor.

Install `dconf` by going to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

to install and then run `dconf-editor`.

Afterwards:

- Navigate to `org/gnome/shell`.
- Select `favorite-apps` toward the bottom of the screen (You may have to scroll down).
- Highlight the text for the app you want to move and drag to it's new location (be careful with the location of commas and quotes).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1131728/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Also: Now it's a _good answer, so have a **+1**!  **;-)**

Comment: Thank you for that; it's the easiest way I've found so far. Sadly, not as easy as Ubuntu 16.04 was, where you could just drag'n'drop the icons on the desktop. It seems like lots of Ubuntu 18.04 has gone backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice this problem when I was running 18.04, but I've done a clean install of 20.04 and I have this issue. On 20.04 I found the icons can be rearranged by a left click, hold, and drag quickly before the menu pops up (about one second) and the icons will drag. Maybe this works for 18.04, too.

Gnome desktop is getting like a game and you have to find the treasures. I like Gnome overall but this is annoying. Now that I fixed it, I forgot what I was doing before...